# How to use lcov with makefile

Tags: c, linux, unit-testing, makefile, googletest

### Introduction

Currently, I'm making a simple C project to try Googletest and coverage testing with lcov.

The repo of the project: https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/Poke-42/tree/21-add-sonarcloud

#### Ressources:

makefile:

```
# Thanks to Job Vranish (https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/08/26/makefile-c-projects/)
TARGET_NAME := Poke42

BUILD_DIR := ./build
SRC_DIRS := ./src
TARGET = $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_NAME)

SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name '*.c')
OBJS := $(SRCS:%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)

INC_DIRS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -type d)
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS))
HEADERS = $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name '*.h')

CC = clang
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic 
CFLAGS += -g3
CFLAGS += $(INC_FLAGS)
CFLAGS += -MMD -MP 

all: run

.PHONY: build
build: $(TARGET)

.PHONY: run
run: $(TARGET)
    @echo "\nrunning $^ !\n"
    @./$^

.PHONY: re
re: clean build

# Linking
$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    @echo "Linking"
    @$(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

# Compile C
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: %.c
    @echo "Compiling $<"
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean: test_clean
    @echo "Clean up"
    @$(RM) -r $(BUILD_DIR)

.PHONY: format
format:
    @echo Formatting
    @bash aux/norme.sh

.PHONY: check
check: re
    @cppcheck --language=c $(SRCS)
    @cppcheck --language=c $(HEADERS)
    @echo
    @python3 -c 'print("-" * 80)'
    @echo SAINTE NORMINETTE SOIS CLEMENTE
    @python3 -c 'print("-" * 80)'
    @echo
    @norminette $(SRCS)
    @echo
    @norminette $(HEADERS)


.PHONY: update
update:
    make clean
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    bear --output $(BUILD_DIR)/compile_commands.json -- make build

# aliases
.PHONY: b r f c u
b: build
r: run
f: format
c: clean
u: update

-include $(DEPS)

###############################################################################

TEST_EXEC_NAME = tests.out

TEST_BUILD_DIR = ./test/build
TEST_SRC_DIR = ./test/src

TEST_TARGET = $(TEST_BUILD_DIR)/$(TEST_EXEC_NAME)

TEST_SRC  = $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name '*.c' -or -name '*.cpp' | grep -v 'main')
TEST_SRC += $(shell find $(TEST_SRC_DIR) -name '*.c' -or -name '*.cpp')

TEST_OBJECTS  := $(TEST_SRC:%=$(TEST_BUILD_DIR)/%.o)

TEST_INC_DIRS := $(shell find $(TEST_SRC_DIR) -type d)
TEST_INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(TEST_INC_DIRS))

CXX = clang++
CXXFLAGS  = $(CFLAGS) 
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17
CXXFLAGS += $(TEST_INC_FLAGS)
CXXFLAGS += -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage

GTESTFLAGS = --gtest_color=yes --gtest_print_time=0
GTESTFLAGS += --gtest_break_on_failure

LDLIBS   = -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread -lgcov

LDFLAGS = -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage

.PHONY: test
test: clean $(TEST_TARGET) coverage
    ./$(TEST_TARGET) $(GTEST_FLAGS)

$(TEST_TARGET): $(TEST_OBJECTS)
    @echo Linking test binary
    @$(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

# compile C
$(TEST_BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: %.c
    @echo "Compiling $<"
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# compile C++
$(TEST_BUILD_DIR)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    @echo Compiling $<
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: coverage
coverage:
    lcov --capture --directory $(TEST_BUILD_DIR) --output-file coverage.info
    genhtml coverage.info --output-directory coverage

.PHONY: test_clean
test_clean:
    rm -rf $(TEST_BUILD_DIR)

.PHONY: format_tests
format_tests:
    clang-format -i $(TEST_SRC)
```

### Problem

When I execute the command `make test` to generate the coverage I obtain this error:

```bash
rm -rf ./test/build
Clean up
Compiling src/combat/action.c
Compiling src/io/input.c
Compiling src/io/output.c
Compiling src/temp.c
Compiling test/src/test.cpp
Linking test binary
lcov --capture --directory ./test/build --output-file coverage.info
Capturing coverage data from ./test/build
Subroutine read_intermediate_text redefined at /usr/bin/geninfo line 2623.
Subroutine read_intermediate_json redefined at /usr/bin/geninfo line 2655.
Subroutine intermediate_text_to_info redefined at /usr/bin/geninfo line 2703.
Subroutine intermediate_json_to_info redefined at /usr/bin/geninfo line 2792.
Subroutine get_output_fd redefined at /usr/bin/geninfo line 2872.
Subroutine print_gcov_warnings redefined at /usr/bin/geninfo line 2900.
Subroutine process_intermediate redefined at /usr/bin/geninfo line 2930.
Found gcov version: 11.3.0
Using intermediate gcov format
Scanning ./test/build for .gcda files ...
geninfo: WARNING: no .gcda files found in ./test/build - skipping!
Finished .info-file creation
genhtml coverage.info --output-directory coverage
Reading data file coverage.info
genhtml: ERROR: no valid records found in tracefile coverage.info
make: *** [Makefile:139: coverage] Error 255
```

### Question

Does someone know how we can add a coverage test with lcov in a simple makefile?

Comment: Do you know how to compile and link your program with coverage analysis using manual commands? I suggest to remove the `@` to see the commands that get executed and compare with the expected options.

Comment: You need `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage`  flags at linking step too.

Comment: @HubertBossy Thank you for your comment! I have updated the question for your comment.

Comment: Is the test binary actually run before running lcov? You won't have any .gcda files before you start it.

Comment: @ThrowsError which compiler u using?

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77215672/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: It is deleted now (limited visibility).